# Race condition between select and update

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to update a row in an Oracle database in a way that I don't silently clobber the changes from another client in my web based application.

In my current system I perform the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:ID AND lastmodified=:LASTMOD
```

if the row still exists with the same last modified date when we started we know nobody has changed it so we can update using the last modified time.

However when doing this manually using two sessions I noticed if two clients select at roughly the same time its possible for one to miss that the row has been changed between the select and update step due to both occurring within the same second or millisecond.

The end result is that I clobber the changes of the other user and there is no warning that it occurred.

I was thinking of using SELECT FROM UPDATE but apparently that's a [bad idea](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_select_for_update.htm) (especially for web apps), the article recommends re-reading (which is what I'm doing above) but I still think I'm at risk of a race condition.

*Edit:* Made it clear I was concerned about the way time is referenced.

Comment: I think the article to which you link is highly dubious.  There are far more grievious banes in a DBA's life than SELECT FOR UPDATE.  For instance, processes which execute gazillions of unnecessary reads and do oodles of extra work instead of having a proper locking strategy.

Comment: The actual problem with SELECT FOR UPDATE is that it is *stateful* whereas HTTP is *stateless*.  Using a technology designed for reading documents to implement OLTP apps is just insane, and a source of unending grief, but apparently we're an industry of masochists 8-)

Comment: I was also reading http://broadh2o.net/docs/database/oracle/oracleLocks.html while research this question, I was concerned about how locking could get stuck even after you disconnect "... terminating a process does not always release locks. Switching off your workstation before you go home does not always release locks. Locks are released only when changes are committed or rolled back." So I was concerned about what would happen if I did a select for update and then didn't rollback  (although I guess this would still be a risk if I had an uncommitted update since that would also lock the row)?

Comment: This is the problem with STFW.  Sure there's loads of marvellous information out there but Google results also throw up dodgy articles.  Any article on locking which doesn't mention PMON and its role in tidying up zombie processes - specifically *releasing locks* - is incomplete and unreliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `UPDATE` statement itself is verifying the `lastmodified` value that you read in your `SELECT` statement as ninesided suggests.

If `lastmodified` is a `DATE`, then there is a potential race condition if there are multiple updates to the same row in the same second since a `DATE` only has granularity to the second.  If `lastmodified` is a `TIMESTAMP`, on the other hand, the window in which the race condition can occur is much more limited since a `TIMESTAMP` will have between 3 and 9 digits of sub-second precision (3 on most Windows machines, 6 on most Unix machines).  It's pretty unlikely though not impossible that you'd have two updates at the same millisecond or even the same microsecond.  But it's not infallible.

You can use a sequence-generated value instead of a last modified date.  That can guarantee that you won't lose an update since a NOCYCLE sequence won't return the same value twice.  But if you go down that path, you're either losing the information benefit of having a last update date on every row or you're storing a few extra bytes of data in every row of the table.  Either of those trade-offs may be worth it depending on your application or either might create more problems than it resolves.

Comment: I was never a big fan of "unlikely though not impossible", sequences it is! Thanks Justin.

Answer (score 1):

one approach you could take is that when a user updates the table, they add

```
AND lastmodified = :LASTMOD
```

to the `WHERE` clause of the update statement, where `:LASTMOD` is the value returned by the user's original select. If the update affected now rows (`SQL%ROWCOUNT=0`) then you know that a second user has updated that row since the first user originally ran their select.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about an SQL internal solution, but I assume you're using some scripting language (php? perl?) to perform the web app/backend stuff, so you could simply use these to use a file lock or semaphore/mutex to lock writing and wait (if locked) or simply tell the user to wait a moment and try again.

As an alternative, you could have a look at the MediaWiki source. I know they've got a protection to avoid two users overwriting each other's content in the DB. And to be honest, I really think that Wikipedia would be quite a huge example of a platform, where such concurrent editing might happen more than once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Another choice would be to enable `ROWDEPENDENCIES` on the table (which requires rebuilding the table!) and use the `ORA_ROWSCN` pseudocolumn.  Tracking the SCN at a row- versus block-level costs 6 bytes per row; however, that's smaller than either a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP` column, and requires no additional objects to be created - like a sequence, or a trigger to make sure the sequence is populated.

For more, see Tom Kyte's asktom question [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:517105100346104196).